# appcmd cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'add' with unique key attribute 'file extension' set to '.txt'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, batch-file, iis, cmd

Trying to allow specific file types in IIS via the appcmd. Using this code:

```
appcmd.exe set config "Default Web Site" -section:system.webServer/security/requestFiltering /+"fileExtensions.[fileExtension='.txt',allowed='True']"
```

If the file extension is already listed in IIS to be either allowed or denied I get this error:

```
cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'add' with unique key attribute 'file extension' set to '.txt'
```

I think I need to remove the specific file extension allow/deny rules in IIS before adding them back, but I don't know how to do that via appcmd.

Comment: [Getting Started with AppCmd.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/getting-started-with-appcmdexe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to add specific file types:

```
appcmd.exe set config "Default Web Site" -section:system.webServer/security/requestFiltering /+"fileExtensions.[fileExtension='.txt']"
```

Use this to remove specific file types:

```
appcmd.exe set config "Default Web Site" -section:system.webServer/security/requestFiltering /-"fileExtensions.[fileExtension='.txt']"
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you so much. Follow up question: Do you know if there is a way to remove ALL specific file types listed in IIS? I tried using a wild card (*) as the file extension but got an error message.

Answer (score 0):

Change the "+" in front of fileExtensions to "-" to remove config

```
appcmd.exe set config "Default Web Site" -section:system.webServer/security/requestFiltering /-"fileExtensions.[fileExtension='.txt',allowed='True']"
```